# How to use the Lyapunov definition of stability?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is as follows:
How to use the Lyapunov definition of stability to determine whether the SOLUTION of an ODE is stable (not a system of ODE's and not the zero solution); this is exactly how it's stated in the sheet for the following ODE's:

$3(t-1)\dot{x}=x ; x(2)=0$

$\dot{x}=t-x ; x(0)=1$

$2t\dot{x}=x-x^2 ; x(0)=0$

Now this frankly this has got me puzzled, I thought that stability is studied only for equilibrium points, and I don't get why the values of $x$ for specific values of $t$ are given with every ODE?

Does it maybe mean for example in the first one to study the stability in the point $(2,0)$ since $x(2)=0$? and if so how can I proceed I don't know how to use the Lyapunov definition of stability for such problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say we have the following ODE:

$$\dot{x} = f(x,t),$$

in which $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Now, imagine we were lucky to find a reference solution $x_{\text{R}}(t)$. Then we introduce a new variable $z(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and substitute

$$x(t) = z(t)+x_{\text{R}}(t)$$

into our ODE to obtain and add and subtract an additional term

$$\dot{z}+\dot{x}_{\text{R}}=f(z+x_{\text{R}},t)$$
$$\dot{z}+\dot{x}_{\text{R}}=f(z+x_{\text{R}},t)-f(x_{\text{R}},t)+f(x_{\text{R}},t).$$

Note, that in this new ODE $z(t)$ is the function that we want to determine, while $x_{\text{R}}$ is known to us and it satisfies the ODE. Hence we can eliminate some terms to obtain

$$\dot{z}=f(z+x_{\text{R}},t)-f(x_{\text{R}},t).$$

First, we notice that $z(t)=0$ is a trivial solution to this system. Additionally, we see that the right-hand side is just a function of $z,t$ with an additional known function $x_{\text{R}}$ as a parameter. Hence, we can write it as

$$\dot{z}=\hat{f}(z,t;x_{\text{R}}).$$

As noted in the previous passage $z=0$ is now a trivial solution to this system.